# PHP - Update a text at different hours of the day

Tags: php, variables, time

Hey guys so i have this script that should theoretically update the text at certain hours in the day but for some reason it only echoes out 1 and i can't figure out why

Any help would be greatly appreciate

```
<?php 

$dt = new DateTime();

$time = $dt->format("H");

if($time = 0){ 
   echo("<h3>0</h3>"); 
}else if($time = 1){ 
    echo("<h3>1</h3>"); 
}else if($time = 2){ 
    echo("<h3>2</h3>");
}else if($time = 3){ 
    echo("<h3>3</h3>");
}else if($time = 4){ 
    echo("<h3>4</h>");
}else if($time = 5){ 
    echo("<h3>5</h3>"); 
}else if($time = 6){ 
    echo("<h3>6</h3>"); 
}else if($time = 7){ 
    echo("<h3>7</h3>");
}else if($time = 8){ 
    echo("<h3>8</h3>"); 
}else if($time = 9){ 
    echo("<h3>9</h3>"); 
}else if($time = 10){ 
    echo("<h3>10</h3>");  
}else if($time = 11){ 
    echo("<h3>11</h3>");  
}else if($time = 12){ 
    echo("<h3>12</h3>");
}else if($time = 13){ 
    echo("<h3>13</h3>");
}else if($time = 14){ 
    echo("<h3>14</h3>");
}else if($time = 15){ 
    echo("<h3>15</h3>");
}else if($time = 16){ 
    echo("<h3>16</h3>");
}else if($time = 17){ 
    echo("<h3>17</h3>");
}else if($time = 18){ 
    echo("<h3>18</h3>");
}else if($time = 19){ 
    echo("<h3>19</h3>");
}else if($time = 20){ 
    echo("<h3>20</h3>");
}else if($time = 21){ 
    echo("<h3>21</h3>");
}else if($time = 22){ 
    echo("<h3>22</h3>");
}else if($time = 23){ 
    echo("<h3>23</h3>");
}else{ 
    echo("<h3>0</h3>");  
} 
?>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `==` for comparing to integers. With `=` you are assigning the value `0` to variable `$time`.

That is, do: `if($time == 0){...}` for all your `if` clauses.

Comment: Thank you man, can't believe i used = instead of == 

Swear i'm not with it today haha, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use a single `=` (assignment) rather than a double `==` (comparison). In effect, you're *setting* the value of $time to 1 in the first `if` statement.

Also, you should just use the value, rather than specifying it for every single possibility. This is horrible spaghetti code. The whole thing could be simplified to:

```
if ($time < 0 || $time > 23) $time = 0;
echo "<h3>{$time}</h3>";
```

And even the `if` part of that is unnecessary, as it's impossible for the value to be outside of the 0..23 range if the DateTime class is coded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
if($time == 0){echo("<h3>0</h3>");}
```

Answer (score 0):

repale all = with ==

```
<?php 

$dt = new DateTime();

$time = $dt->format("H");

if($time == 0){ 
   echo("<h3>0</h3>"); 
}else if($time == 1){ 
    echo("<h3>1</h3>"); 
}else if($time == 2){ 
    echo("<h3>2</h3>");
}else if($time == 3){ 
    echo("<h3>3</h3>");
}else if($time == 4){ 
    echo("<h3>4</h>");
}else if($time == 5){ 
    echo("<h3>5</h3>"); 
}else if($time == 6){ 
    echo("<h3>6</h3>"); 
}else if($time == 7){ 
    echo("<h3>7</h3>");
}else if($time == 8){ 
    echo("<h3>8</h3>"); 
}else if($time == 9){ 
    echo("<h3>9</h3>"); 
}else if($time == 10){ 
    echo("<h3>10</h3>");  
}else if($time == 11){ 
    echo("<h3>11</h3>");  
}else if($time == 12){ 
    echo("<h3>12</h3>");
}else if($time == 13){ 
    echo("<h3>13</h3>");
}else if($time == 14){ 
    echo("<h3>14</h3>");
}else if($time == 15){ 
    echo("<h3>15</h3>");
}else if($time == 16){ 
    echo("<h3>16</h3>");
}else if($time == 17){ 
    echo("<h3>17</h3>");
}else if($time == 18){ 
    echo("<h3>18</h3>");
}else if($time == 19){ 
    echo("<h3>19</h3>");
}else if($time == 20){ 
    echo("<h3>20</h3>");
}else if($time == 21){ 
    echo("<h3>21</h3>");
}else if($time == 22){ 
    echo("<h3>22</h3>");
}else if($time == 23){ 
    echo("<h3>23</h3>");
}else{ 
    echo("<h3>0</h3>");  
} 
?>
```